# Javascript metaprogramming: get name of currently executing function which was dynamically rewritten

Tags: javascript, function, dynamic, metaprogramming

I am rewriting one of javascript's core methods:

```
Element.prototype._removeChild = Element.prototype.removeChild;
Element.prototype.removeChild = function(){
    callback();
    this._removeChild.apply(this,arguments);
}
```

I want to dynamically get the name of the method (in this case "removeChild") from inside of the function being dynamically rewritten. I use `arguments.callee.name` but it seems to return nothing, thinking that it is just an anonymous function. How do I get the name of the function that the anonymous function is being assigned to?

Comment: Javascript doesn't have methods. Only functions assigned to properties. In this case, `Element.prototype.removeChild` is one property where it is assigned, it can also be assigned to somewhere else at the same time. It is not the function's name, it doesn't have a name. The function doesn't know how many properties it is assigned to or what properties it is assigned to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It *is* an anonymous function. You are just assigning this anonymous function to the `Element.prototype.removeChild` property, but that does not make that property a name for the function. You can assign the same function to many variables and properties, and there is no way to know the name by which it has been called.

You can however give the function a proper name which you can access as `arguments.callee.name`:

```
Element.prototype.removeChild = function removeChild() {
    ....
}
```

Comment: +1 This is perfect because then the function can refer to itself by `removeChild`, but `removeChild` is still undefined outside the function. Except in IE 8 and below which doesn't really implement Javascript correctly. In IE 8 and under `removeChild` is exposed to the outer scope (possible global) unless you wrap a closure around the whole thing: `(function(){ Element.prototype.removeChild = function removeChild() { ... } )();`

Comment: Since you gave the function a name, you can use the name instead of deprecated `arguments.callee`. But then again, `removeChild.name` ...:P

Comment: On second thought, IE apparently does not support the (non-standard) `Function.prototype.name` property, so the `arguments.callee.name` approach is not portable.

Comment: @lanzz Function#name was standardized in ES6.